# How can I use the xsrf_cookies setting in tornado at ease？

Tags: tornado, csrf

Good afternoon, everyone~

As we know, when I add the `xsrf_cookies = True` in the settings of tornado,I should use `xsrf_form_html()` in the template, also , should do something if I choose sending message by ajax.

But,what should I do or set the tornado ,when I want have both the xsrf_cookies and not xsrf_cookies. En,it means,I want it could check the xsrf and could not check the xsrf by my thought.Maybe I could not explain it clearly?

For example,in Django,we can use `@csrf_exempt` not check csrf when we add the check-xsrf to middleware.

Hope I explained it enough~

Now, I want anyone can tell me:
1,Did here any way like the example in tornado?If has,told me please~ 
2,If not ,what should I do, if I must add the 'check' and 'not check' together?

Comment: One way I think about is : set the xsrf_cookies = False and write some other method  to realize the same function？But it seem not pythonic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://tornado-zh.readthedocs.io/zh/latest/guide/security.html

In the end of the page,it shows the `RequestHandler.check_xsrf_cookie()`.

En,it is the chinese version.

It shows,I can overide the check_xsrf_cookie like below:

```
def check_xsrf_cookie(self):
    pass
```

En,throuth the source:

```
def check_xsrf_cookie(self):
    token = (self.get_argument("_xsrf", None) or
             self.request.headers.get("X-Xsrftoken") or
             self.request.headers.get("X-Csrftoken"))
    if not token:
        raise HTTPError(403, "'_xsrf' argument missing from POST")
    _, token, _ = self._decode_xsrf_token(token)
    _, expected_token, _ = self._get_raw_xsrf_token()
    if not token:
        raise HTTPError(403, "'_xsrf' argument has invalid format")
    if not _time_independent_equals(utf8(token), utf8(expected_token)):
        raise HTTPError(403, "XSRF cookie does not match POST argument")
```

It seems to be :

check the xsrf ,raise error or return None.

So, overide `pass` maybe enough.